Sequelize doesn't fetch the assosiated model with a GET request
Sequelize doesn't fetch the assosiated model in the get request, but it works in the POST and DELETE requests with two parameters provided. I have an M-M relationship between the Worker and Owner id(foreign keys are userId and establishmentId). I want to retrieve the establishments associated with user and vice versa. But it returns an empty query, my associations are as follows:
Worker
      Worker.belongsTo(models.User, { 
        foreignKey: 'userId',  
      });
      Worker.belongsToMany(models.Establishment, { 
        foreignKey: 'userId', 
        through: models.Workers_Establishments,  
      });
      Worker.belongsTo(models.Owner, { 
        foreignKey: 'ownerId',  
      });

Establishment
      Establishment.belongsTo(models.Owner, { 
        foreignKey: 'ownerId',  
      });
      Establishment.hasMany(models.Promotion, { 
        foreignKey: 'establishmentId', 
        onDelete: 'CASCADE', 
        onUpdate: 'CASCADE'
      });
      Establishment.belongsToMany(models.Worker, { 
        foreignKey: 'establishmentId',
        through: models.Workers_Establishments,  
      });

Workers_Establishments(Junction)
      Workers_Establishments.belongsTo(models.Worker, { 
        foreignKey: 'userId',  
      });
      Workers_Establishments.belongsTo(models.Establishment, { 
        foreignKey: 'establishmentId',  
      });

The query in question
async function getEstablishmentsByWorker(userId){
    const establishments = await db.Establishment.findAll({
        include: {
            model: db.Worker,
            where: {
                userId: userId
            },
            through: db.Workers_Establishments
        }
    })

    return establishments;
}

I tried to use through with db.Workers_Establishment, doesn't work

Did you try to indicate otherKey in both belongsToMany associations? Could you show the generated SQL?

Added the sourceKey and targetKey to models. That solved the issue.
